# Telerik.Everlive.SDK File Upload Error - Bad Gateway 502

Tags: telerik, xamarin.forms

I am trying to upload a file ("abc.jpg") using Telerik.Everlive.SDK library, but I keep getting bad gateway error.

Here is my code:

```
var fileField = new Telerik.Everlive.Sdk.Core.Query.Definition.FormData.FileField("file","abc.jpg","image/jpeg", stream);

var result = EverliveAppContext.WorkWith().Files().Upload(fileField).ExecuteSync();
```

I am getting following exception while executing above code:

> Telerik.Everlive.Sdk.Core.Transport.EverliveException: \r\n502 Bad Gateway\r\n\r\n
>
> ## 502 Bad Gateway
>
> \r\n
>
> ---
>
> nginx\r\n\r\n\r\n ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.\n  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x0033b] in :0 \n  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00165] in :0 \n  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\n  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in :0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in :0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in :0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in :0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[Telerik.Everlive.Sdk.Core.Model.Result.CreateResultItem].GetResult () [0x00000] in :0 \n  at Stream.Data.Repository+Files+d__1.MoveNext () [0x0008f] in e:\PROJECTS\GIT\StreamLive\common\Entities\Repository.cs:218